# index numbers of a word

Tags: string, python-2.7

Just trying to write a basic function where the function should print index numbers of a certain letter in a word for.

Below is the function is wrote. It is only printing out the first index a the letter I give

```
def ind_fnd(word, char):
    """
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "o")
    '2 5 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "l")
    '3 4 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "n")
    ''
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "a")
    '0'
    """
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word [index] == char:
            return index
        index += 1
```

please help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, "What's wrong with my code?" is not a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
>
> Return the lowest index in s where
> the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in
> s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and
> interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Meaning it will find the first instance.

Rather than using find(), you can go through every character and see if the character you are looking for is present.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach a in word:
   if char is a:
      x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def ind_fnd(word, char):
...     places = []
...     for k in range(0, len(word)):
...             if word[k] == char:
...                     places.append(k)
...     return places
... 
>>> ind_fnd("apollo", "o")
[2, 5]
>>>
```

Use a `for` loop to loop once per character in the word. Then you check if the character at `k` is the character you are looking for. If so, add it to `places`. At the end, return `places`.

Or, as @wwii said, you can use `enumerate()`, as such:

```
>>> def ind_fnd(word, char):
...     places = []
...     for index, c in enumerate(word):
...             if c == char:
...                     places.append(index)
...     return places
... 
>>> ind_fnd('apollo', 'l')
[3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: ```enumerate()``` might be a better choice for the ```for``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

string.find, much like string.index only returns the first occurence of a letter.

There is a one line solution.

```
def ind_fnd(word, char)
    return [i for i in range(len(word)) if word[i]==char]
```

Comment: ```enumerate()``` makes this *easier* - ```[index for index, character in enumerate(word) if character == char]```